# how to select the data from dropdown list that is equivalent to the ng-model in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

My model is valued as timeSetting.timezone = "34" and I have a dropdown list that has this code

```
 <select class="select len_lg" value={{timeSetting.timezone}} >
     <option value="1">(GMT-12:00) International Data Line West;  </option>
    <option value="2">(GMT-11:00) UTC-11;  </option>
    <option value="3">(GMT-11:00) Samoa;</option>
    <option value="4">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii;</option>
    <option value="5">(GMT-09:00) Alaska; </option>
    <option value="6">(GMT-08:00) Baja California;</option>
    .
    .
    .
    <option value="34">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada);    </option>
```

How can I automatically select in the options list the timezone that has the value equivalent to the value of my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model` does what you want.

```
<select class="select len_lg"  ng-model="timeSetting.timezone">
    <option value="1">(GMT-12:00) International Data Line West; </option>
    <option value="2">(GMT-11:00) UTC-11; </option>
    <option value="3">(GMT-11:00) Samoa;</option>
    <option value="4">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii;</option>
    <option value="5">(GMT-09:00) Alaska; </option>
    <option value="6">(GMT-08:00) Baja California;</option>
    <option value="34">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada);</option>
</select>
```

Here is a plunker with an example http://plnkr.co/edit/gWboXLwnrVpmCW6GdQnW?p=preview

Comment: thanks @IgnacioVillaverde how about if the value of my model the "timeSetting.timezone" which is 34 is from an xml response how can i possibly do that?

Comment: But do you have access to it in the controller?

Comment: Yes I need to access it

Comment: forget it , I would just like to ask now how can I get the value of the dropdown selected for example the value of "(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)" to be the value of another input text?

Comment: In the example that I have built you can see that when you select other option, the value of timezone is automatically binded. $scope.timezone is being set with that selected option.

Comment: but the value shown is also 34. I need the (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada); to be the showed value

Comment: Maybe what you should do is to manage your options with an array. use ng-options, and there you could get whatever you need. Take a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions