# CGI Response and AngularJS ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, xml, cgi

I have a problem getting the equivalent timezone assigned in my model. In my question below, the value of the model timeSetting.timezone which is 34 is from a cgi response. How will I call the respective timezone value assigned to 34 in the dropdown list to also be the value displayed in the input box? There immes an associated plunker in the answer part of my other question.

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select class="select len_lg"  ng-model="timezone">
    <option value="1">(GMT-12:00) International Data Line West; </option>
    <option value="2">(GMT-11:00) UTC-11; </option>
    <option value="3">(GMT-11:00) Samoa;</option>
    <option value="4">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii;</option>
    <option value="5">(GMT-09:00) Alaska; </option>
    <option value="6">(GMT-08:00) Baja California;</option>
    <option value="34">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada);</option>
  </select>
  timezone: {{timezone}}
</body>

<script>var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.timezone = '34';
});
</script>
```

[how to select the data from dropdown list that is equivalent to the ng-model in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006473/how-to-select-the-data-from-dropdown-list-that-is-equivalent-to-the-ng-model-in/35006667?noredirect=1#comment57741419_35006667)

Comment: the plunker link is http://plnkr.co/edit/gWboXLwnrVpmCW6GdQnW?p=preview

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**."

Comment: but I'm not seeking debugging help I just want to ask how can I make the showed value of the model to be the equal value of the selected option in the dropdown list the plunker above is working already but the displayed value of the model in the input type text is '34' @Quentin

Comment: If you have a question about some code that you have, then you need to put the code **in the question** and not just link to some third party hosted version of it.

Comment: I edit it now @Quentin